# How to extend Google App Engine 30 seconds limit?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there anyway to extend GAE 30 seconds limit?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you really have users who are willing to wait longer than 30 seconds for a web page to load?  We may be able to help you better if you tell us what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to implement something that takes a long time to finish, you should probably do so in a backend or using tasks.

You can read more about Backends [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html)
and you can read more about Tasks [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/)

I haven't worked with either, so i can't give a recommendation for either.

Answer (score 11):

If what you need is a slightly higher limit, you don't need to do anything since the limit had been increased to 60 seconds since the last [App Engine 1.5.5 SDK Release](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-155-sdk-release.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the powerful [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) depending on the type of job you're going to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit more information about deadline exceptions, how to spot problematic areas, and some ideas on how to fix them.

[Deadline errors: 60 seconds or less in Google App Engine](http://www.shiftedup.com/2015/03/12/deadline-errors-60-seconds-or-less-in-google-app-engine)

As it was mentioned before, notice that the limit has been increased to 60 seconds.